# How to use NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport.getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(SQL, map, class<>)?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, db2-400

I'm new to Spring, started using NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport class for querying DB2 database. How can I select specific Month records from a table of MySql database??

SQL : `public static final String ACAHEADERARCHIEVEDSQLCARD = "SELECT " + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_AGENT_ID + ", "
            + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_YEAR + ", " + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_NUM + "  FROM "
            + "DUR33M5" + "." + ACAHeaderDBConstants.TABLE + " WHERE "
            + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_AGENT_ID + " =:agentID and " + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_CRDT_CARD_IND
            + " = 'Y' and " + " MONTH( " + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_OPEN_TMSTMP + ") = MONTH( :fromDate ) and "
            + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_CLOSE_DT + " is null WITH UR; ";`

Code :

```
StringBuilder fromDate = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        fromDate.append(archieveDetails.getAcaYear());
        fromDate.append("-");
        fromDate.append(archieveDetails.getAcaMonth());
        fromDate.append("-");
        fromDate.append("01");
        map.put(ACAHeaderDBConstants.AGENTID, agentId);
        map.put("fromDate", fromDate.toString());
        try {
            return getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().queryForObject( ACAHEADERARCHIEVEDSQLCARD, map, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(ACAHeaderInfo.class));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
```

For the above query, i'm facing the following error message :

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT ACA_AGENT_ID, ACA_YEAR, ACA_NUM  FROM DUR33M5.TWEB_ACA_HEADER WHERE ACA_AGENT_ID =? and ACA_CRDT_CARD_IND = 'Y' and  MONTH( ACA_OPEN_TMSTMP) = MONTH( ? ) and ACA_CLOSE_DT is null WITH UR; ]; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.63.123.
```

If i passing the static value like '2017-02-01', instead of dynamic :fromDate from the above query its working fine.

From the above, the piece of query :

```
MONTH( " + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_OPEN_TMSTMP + ") = MONTH( '2017-01-01' )
```

instead of `MONTH( " + ACAHeaderDBConstants.ACA_OPEN_TMSTMP + ") = MONTH( :fromDate )` its working fine.

please any one suggest me, where i'm missing the framework.
Thanks.

Comment: You should be passing a `Date` not a `String` as an argument. When adding it directly to the string first thing that happens is that MySQL turns it into a date before applying it to the `Month` function. However when adding it as a string with argument resolution that isn't happening.

Comment: @M. Deinum, thanks for your feedback. i tried both String and Date object s but facing the same exception.